# Cannot read property 'debugHosts' of undefined

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm getting this error while trying to use Realm with RN 0.29

Stack trace from chrome:

```
"Cannot read property 'debugHosts' of undefined"
handleException @   ExceptionsManager.js:55
handleError @   InitializeJavaScriptAppEngine.js:136
reportFatalError    @   error-guard.js:30
guardedLoadModule   @   require.js:60
_require    @   require.js:49
(anonymous function)    @   require-0.js:1
executeApplicationScript    @   debuggerWorker.js:18
onmessage   @   debuggerWorker.js:33
```

The device is pointing to the index.js file in the `node_modules/realm/lib/index.js` in this line:
`const {debugHosts, debugPort} = NativeModules.Realm;`

One thing I tried was removing all degbugHosts related stuff in the js files, and It throws `Must first create RPC session with a valid host`...

Someone said that it's working on RN 0.28 but I would like to fix it instead of downgrading RN just for this module.

Comment: I am getting the same error. This is a version compatibility issue. Prior to this it was working fine.

Comment: Yea, but how do we fix it? I don't want to downgrade RN just for this if I can avoid it.

Comment: I am also looking for solutions.

Comment: Alright, I fixed it, check answer for solution

Comment: Thanks. I will try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steps to fix:

`rnpm link realm`

Add the module in the MainApplication.Java file, should look like this

```
 @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new RealmReactPackage() // this
      );
    }
  };
```

rebuild/clean/etc

Also, may need to add `android:name=".MainApplication"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml -> <application`

Comment: Solution for iOS?